# PostgreSQL returns JSON with string instead of byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, asp.net-core, byte

I have **bytea** type row in postgreSQL for password hash.

What I want to do is to put it into JSON and get it from c# controller.

I couldn't deserialize the response to byte[], so I did deserialize it to string

```
    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataJSON>(JSONReply.ToString());
```

DataJSON contains "string data" ( instead of byte[] data ).

How to convert this string to byte[] ?

What I've tried is these:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.data);
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data.data);
```

They were both too long (expected length of password hash is 64 bytes).

Any ideas how to convert it?

data.data contains this

```
"\\x862e21d34b4c3178abe7d8ec6d163d0fb400dd4ca483d92e670eb91641c3e178e87c4e62a188679b9443b04f278e8d55d9c62516da131115fd1e1c3d5c3ed448"
```

Comment: Post what that `data.data` string contains.

Comment: @Evk updated post

Comment: So this is hex. You need to remove starting '\x' and then convert from hex to byte array (there are ton of questions on this site about how to do that). Though I wonder why whatever library you use to query data from postgres doesn't do this for you.

Comment: That worked! Could you post it as answer so I can accept it?